# Can't open .gdb folder with related files in ArcMap 10.7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, catalog-window

I am wondering if someone here might be able to help me troubleshoot opening a .gdb folder in ArcMap. I have already tried using Add Layer, Connect to Folder under Catalog, Open, and dragging and dropping the files. None of these have proved fruitful. When I connect to the folder, the folder links but none of the files inside the folder show up and thus cannot be opened in ArcMap.

Comment: Sounds like the dataset is corrupt (or just empty -- Even an *empty* file geodatabase will contain 41 data files, mostly in the form "a0000000{n}.*")

Comment: @Shelly What happens when you connect to the folder above the one with a name ending in .gdb?  If it doesn’t show up with a geodatabase icon in the Catalog window then it’s not a valid file geodatabase.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the parent folder (or higher) that the geodatabase sits inside of in order for ArcGIS to recognize it. Add that parent folder as a folder connection, then open that in the catalog pane and the file geodatabase should show up inside it. Double click that and you will see its contents.